# GoogleMap not showing user's current location properly when drawing path overlay

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using GMSPolyline on google map to show shortest path between two points. This map does not show user's current location properly.

Here is my code. Let me know about the correction that I can make in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

 /////// If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power.

    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (abs(howRecent) < 0.5)
    {

     /////// Update your marker on your map using location.coordinate.latitude
           //and location.coordinate.longitude);

        NSLog(@"event time=%@",eventDate);

#pragma mark start Point of Polyline Drow
 ///////////////Logitude 23.03 apvathe darek point tyathe start thay etle polyline Drow thay/////
        if (location.coordinate.longitude==23.03)
        {
            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        }


        [mypath addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude]];

        GMSMutablePath *path1 = [GMSMutablePath path];

        for (int i=0; i<mypath.count; i++)
        {
            //NSString *str1=mypath[i];
            NSArray* foo = [mypath[i] componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
            NSString* lat = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
            NSString* longi = [foo objectAtIndex: 1];

           [path1 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [longi floatValue])];
        }
        GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path1];
        rectangle.map = mapView_;

            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
            marker.title = @"Gurukul Road,Ahmedabad";
            marker.snippet = @"Gujarat";
            marker.map = mapView_;

    }
}
```

Comment: Add the image properly and show some code please.

Comment: put some code here,if you taking your latitude and longitude in float that might cause problem convert it to double.

Comment: @DeepGami please see my code and help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to be more accurate in case of latitude and longitude you are using there %f and that is not accurate as per values of latitude and longitude use this code...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        strForCurrentLongitude= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        strForCurrentLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

Take Double value instead of float in this line.

```
  [path1 addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat floatValue], [longi floatValue])];
```